# Show/Hide on click dropdownlist MVC 4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this view:

```html
<div class="editor-field">Best</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Best, new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Best3", Text = "Best 3"},
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Best5", Text = "Best 5"},
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Best10", Text = "Best 10"},
        new SelectListItem { Value = "XBest", Text = "X Best"}
    },
    new { @class = "myselect" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Best)
</div> 
<div class="editor-label">X</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.X)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.X)
</div>
```

And I have this jquery:

```js
$('#Best').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "XBest") {
        $('#X').hide(); //invisible
        $('#X').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable
    } else {
        $('#X').show(); //visible
        $('#X').removeAttr('disabled'); // enable
    }
});
```

And it works, but when i go to this view the EditorFor X is always visible, only changes when i start clicking on the values of the dropdownlist. My question is how can it stays hidden when accessing to the view and only shows on click.

Comment: You could just add `$('#Best').trigger('change');` before `$('#Best').on('change', function () {`

Comment: still get the same problem, the editorfor is visible when first accessing the view

Comment: Not unless the selected option is `XBest`. But if you want to hide it even if the selected option is `XBest`, then just use css to style it as `display: none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the `change()` event immediately after binding the event like following.

```
$('#Best').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "XBest") {
        $('#X').hide(); //invisible
        $('#X').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable
    } else {
        $('#X').show(); //visible
        $('#X').removeAttr('disabled'); // enable
    }
}).change(); // auto execute
```

Comment: `$('#Best').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "XBest") {
        $('#X').hide().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#X').show().removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }
}).change();` 
will be the optimized one

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the question is focusing on triggering `change` event not optimizing. @ShashankSood

Comment: that's y added as a comment not an answer

Comment: OK. Then see a more optimized way  `$('#Best').on('change', function() { var isXBest = $(this).val() == "XBest"; $('#X').toggle(isXBest).prop('disabled', !isXBest); }).change();` @ShashankSood